# How to resolve incompatible types?

Tags: android

I am actually new to android studio , Now I am stuck on this Compilation error. Please help..
Following is the problem 
`FragmentActivity activity = this();`
Shows Compilation error

**Incompatible types**

Required: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity

Found: com.example.androidapp.MainActivity

I have used the `getSupportFragementManager()` and `getFragementManager()` ..None of this works..

**Relevant Code**

```
package com.example.androidapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Create a thread pool with a single thread//

        Executor newExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        FragmentActivity activity = this;

//Start listening for authentication events//

        final BiometricPrompt myBiometricPrompt = new BiometricPrompt(activity, newExecutor, new BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
           ...
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing `FragmentManager` and `FragmentActivity`. Those are not the same thing.

Comment: We don't know. What do you actually need; a `FragmentManager`, or a `FragmentActivity`? Your `import` statements don't really tell us anything about the code.

Comment: Please don't just link to code off-site. The specific code that you're having issue with needs to be in the question here.

Comment: Sorry, Please check again have updated the code in my Question.

Comment: Change that first import to `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;`. Aside from that, though, the whole `FragmentActivity activity = this;` and subsequent usage of `activity` are rather pointless. Just use `this`, or `MainActivity.this`, as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the imports & signature:

```
// import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    ...
}
```

Also see [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) for further replacement packages ...

because mixing up `android.support` with `androidx` is problematic.